# How can I compare $\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}X_n$ with $\mathbb{N}\times Y$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Question:

For every $n\in\mathbb{N}$, let $X_n$ and $Y$ to be sets that are not empty.
If for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $X_n\leq Y$, then show $\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}X_n\leq\mathbb{N}\times Y$.

---

Hi,

I don't know how to compare, how can I compare $\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}X_n$ with $\mathbb{N}\times Y$?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you are given a sequence $A$ of sets (indexed by $\mathbb{N}$) together with a set $B$ such that $|A_n|\leqslant|B|$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ -- where by $|M|$ I mean the cardinality of set $M$ -- you have that:
$$\left|\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}A_n\right| \leqslant \left|\bigsqcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}A_n\right|=\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}}|A_n|\leqslant \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}}|B|=|\mathbb{N}||B|=|\mathbb{N} \times B|.$$

For a given family $T$ of sets indexed by set $I$ I am using the notation:
$$\bigsqcup_{i \in I}T_i\colon=\bigcup_{i \in I}\{i\} \times T_i$$
to refer to its *disjoint union*.

Comment: Should I use A and B's, why you did not use Xn and Y?
And... can we show it with partially ordered relation's properties?

and, where did M come from?

Comment: @Colleg an Delta 1) There is no obligation to use one set of characters rather than others, in your notation. One is essentially free to choose the letters of his preference, as long as he declares his customs of notation. 2) The inequalities I produced above are based on the properties of the relation of *total order* existing between cardinal numbers, each and everyone has a justification that I did not take the time to expand in full detail (it would have turned my answer into a mini-lecture on cardinal theory and set-theoretical constructions) *(to be cont.)*

Comment: @Colleg an Delta *(cont.)* 3) $M$ came from the need to declare my notation of using $||$ around the name of a set in order to refer to the cardinality of that set. I just happened to choose the letter $M$ to name that generic set.

Comment: Thank you, Sir.

Comment: @Colleg an Delta My pleasure, I am glad if it helped!